In spherical multipole expansion, why does the hexadecapole (16-pole) only have 12 "poles?"
Below is an image of real spherical harmonics in wikipedia.

These are used in different scenarios, but when they represent charge distributions on a spherical shell (see e.g. this awesome answer), then from top to bottom, the successive rows lead to monopole, dipole, quadruple, octopole, ... terms in the spherical multipole expansion. Better yet, unlike the heuristic point-charge poles in Cartesian coordinates, each of these mutipole spherical distributions never produces any residual higher multipole terms 1. These are pure multipoles.
For me, this should be the origin of the $n$-pole naming. Because you really can count at most 1, 2, 4, 8 "poles" (or rather protrusions) in the charge configurations in the rows $s,p,d,f$. However this correspondence stops at octopole. For the hexadecapole, or 16-pole, you count in the $g$ row. But the most "poles" you get is 12 poles for the $m=3$ charge configuration.
So, where should I count to find 16 "poles" for multipole expansion?
1: For example, a pair of $+/-$ point charges placed at $±z$ is our textbook dipole, but in this configuration they have nonvanishing octopole electrostatic potential and other higher-pole potentials.

what exactly are you counting to get $(1, 2, 4, 8, 12)$ w.r.t $(s, p, d, f, g)$? And why are you looking at $m=3$ for $l=4$? And finally, the "for example"...what is that exemplifying?

The $2^\ell$-pole naming reflects the fact that you can construct a multipole of order $\ell$ by placing two equal and opposite multipoles of order $\ell$-1 at a distance from each other. Don't read any more into it than that.

I'm not sure what it is you are thinking you would be getting. If you look at all the $m=0$, the number of lobes is $\ell+1$, whereas if you look at all the $m=\pm1$, you see that the number of lobes is $2\ell$; it is clearly not $2^\ell$ as you were hoping.
